# There are Suspect Pages but DBCC CHECKDB returned no errors?

Tags: sql-server, corruption, dbcc-checkdb

As the question states, there are 3 suspect pages on a database, but when I ran DBCC CHECKDB (DB, REPIAR_REBUILD), after almost 4 hours, it completed with no errors. I know suspect pages might not actually be corrupted, but suspect_pages shows hundreds of errors on these pages. Should I try the repair again, but this time to allow for data loss? Or is there another way to fix it? The first two pages are event type 1, while the last is event type 2, all with a last_update_date on the same day several months ago.

Comment: If they're all that old there's a good chance that they've long since been deallocated.